# Regex Match Pattern with Some Exceptions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find matches for Instagram handles but ignore specific handles.

I'm using

`@[A-Za-z0-9\.\_]+`

to match any handle starting with an `@` sign, but I want to ignore handles like `@example` and `@test` which for that I have the regex `@example|@test`.

New to regex and trying to figure out how to do the look ahead and ignore the example and test cases. Not sure how to combine the two into one.

Comment: Do you want to return `@test.user`?

Comment: Like this: `@(?!(?:test|example)$)[\w.]+` ?

Comment: I'm just looking through a text field using something like df['regex_handle'] = df['TEXT'].str.contains('@[A-Za-z0-9\.\_]+')== True so I want it to return False if it has example or test in it

Comment: So, `@tester` should not be returned, right? Or `@test.me`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

`@(?!example|test)[A-Za-z0-9._]+`

Uses negative lookahead to ignore the handles that are not required.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/10/)

Comment: This will also fail to match `@tester`.

Comment: Yes, it will only match "test" exactly which is what I wanted